# Use segmentcontroller to change tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoapods, segment

I want to use XMSegmentController(https://cocoapods.org/?q=segmen) to change the different tableview,I do not know what is missing in my program, which leads to a black situation when I run. Does anyone know what to add to my program? Thank you.

Here is mt code:

```
import UIKit
import XMSegmentedControl

class ViewController: UIViewController, XMSegmentedControlDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl1: XMSegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview1: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview2: UITableView!

    let one = ["1","2","3"]
    let two = ["4","5","6"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        segmentedControl1.delegate = self
        segmentedControl1.segmentTitle = ["One", "Two"]

     }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "left", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = one[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "right", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = two[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if tableView == self.tableview1 {
            return one.count
        }
        return two.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }


    func xmSegmentedControl(_ xmSegmentedControl: XMSegmentedControl, selectedSegment: Int) {
        if xmSegmentedControl == segmentedControl1 {
            print("SegmentedControl1 Selected Segment: \(selectedSegment)")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use a Container View Controller with two `UITableViewController`s as its children. It's much more flexible incase you want to add more segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your controller as initial ViewController to show your Controller. Now use `selectedSegment` argument from delegate method and `hide/show` the `tableView` according to it.

```
func xmSegmentedControl(_ xmSegmentedControl: XMSegmentedControl, selectedSegment: Int) {
    if xmSegmentedControl == segmentedControl1 {
        tableview1.isHidden = selectedSegment != 0
        tableview2.isHidden = selectedSegment != 1
    }
}
```

Also instead of using two `tableView` you can use single `tableView` like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if segmentedControl1.selectedSegment == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "left", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = one[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "right", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = two[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if segmentedControl1.selectedSegment == 0 {
        return one.count
    }
    return two.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

And in delegate method of `xmSegmentedControl` simply reload the tableView.

```
func xmSegmentedControl(_ xmSegmentedControl: XMSegmentedControl, selectedSegment: Int) {
    if xmSegmentedControl == segmentedControl1 {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem!

Comment: @廖豪豪 Welcome mate :) Also check edited answer and ignore the use of multiple tableView

Comment: I would like to try, wait for you to reply, thank you

Answer (score 1):

what is your initial ViewController?can you please check in your storyboard?

set an initial viewcontroller.

```
func xmSegmentedControl(_ xmSegmentedControl: XMSegmentedControl, selectedSegment: Int) {
    if xmSegmentedControl == segmentedControl1 {
        tableviewOne.isHidden = selectedSegment != 0
        tableviewSecond.isHidden = selectedSegment != 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Only ViewController in my storyboard, and initial viewcontroller is ViewController

Comment: Opps,I forgot to do what you say, but how to switch tableview?

Comment: yes i think u forgot to add an intial viewcontroller.do that first and i am editting my answer for switching.